# Redundancy in the commandment to multiply

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit

> וְאַתֶּם פְּרוּ וּרְבוּ שִׁרְצוּ בָאָרֶץ וּרְבוּ־בָהּ׃
>   Be fertile, then, and increase; abound on the earth and increase on it.” ([Ber 9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.9.7?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

Why the repetition of רבו - increase?

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch explains that the second רבו is a modification of the שרצו which is a new commandment over and above the basic fruitfulness of the world.

[Noach 9:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8173/showrashi/true#v7)

As Rashi says:

> And you, be fruitful and multiply: According to its simple meaning:
>   the first [mention of this expression] (verse 1) was a blessing, and
>   this [mention] is a commandment. According to its midrashic
>   interpretation, [it is written here] to compare one who does not
>   engage in propagation to one who sheds blood. — [from Yev. 63b]

Rav Hirsch comments:

> שרצו בארץ ורבו בה - a highly significant addition to the mission of
>   development given here to the Noachian world with which this whole new
>   constitution of humanity concludes. Its meaning is given by רשבל in
>   בראשית רבה by the explanation ברית נחלק לאוירות, that Hashem gave a
>   special covenant, a special dispensation, to the different climates
>   and countries. שרץ, as already shown, is the name given to the lowest
>   stage of life, according to the essential sign of its exitence,
>   movement, ישרצו המים. Inasmuch as here the procreation and propagation
>   of the human race have this designation added, the term would
>   represent a swarm of the most manifold different kinds of men,. It
>   would accordingly be a description of a diversity and infinite variety
>   of human races, and moreover בארץ, on the earth, and by the earth,
>   under the influences of the differences of the various lands. And not
>   only שרצו בארץ but also רבו - the whole physical, moral, and
>   intellectual education - equally בה, under the same influences.